# Implementing copy constructor in a single linked list C++

Tags: c++, constructor, linked-list, destructor, copy-constructor

I have a C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Node;

typedef Node *NodePtr;

struct Node
{
    int Item;
    NodePtr Next;
};

class LinkedList
{
public:
    LinkedList();                   // default constructor
    ~LinkedList();                  // destructor
    void AddTail(int);              // adds item to tail
private:
    NodePtr Head;
};

LinkedList::LinkedList()
{
    Head = NULL; //declare head as null
}
//Adding on tail
void LinkedList::AddTail(int Item)
{
    NodePtr Crnt;
    NodePtr node = new Node;
    node->Item = Item;
    node->Next = NULL;
//if head is in null declare the added node as head
    if (Head == NULL)
    {
        Head = node;
    }
    else
    { //set the current to head, move the current node to current next node
        Crnt = Head;
        while (Crnt->Next != NULL)
        {
            Crnt = Crnt->Next;
        }
        //Add item to the tail of the linked list
        Crnt->Next = node;
    }
}

int main()
{
    LinkedList la;
    la.AddTail(30);
    la.AddTail(60);
    la.AddTail(90);
    LinkedList lb;
    return 0;
}
```

So my question is how do I implement a copy constructor(suppose on object lb) that makes a deep copy of the list argument and also adding code for testing the copy constructor on empty and non-empty lists? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Easy way should be to iterate the list to be copied and call the `AddTail` method for each element in the list. But hey, if you want a copy constructor, you'll want an assignment operator to go with it. [May I suggest the Copy and Swap Idiom?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom)

Comment: Can you please post the code?

Comment: @Pattrick, please post the code that you have tried to implement copy constructor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the big rules of programing is Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY). If you have a function that adds and you know it works, keep using it for add-related jobs. This means it's in your best interest to keep add dead stupid and versatile.

Applying the DRY philosophy, the Copy Constructor, assuming the `AddTail` method works correctly, is astonishingly simple: Call `AddTail` for every node in the source list.

```
LinkedList::LinkedList(const LinkedList & src):Head(nullptr)
{
    NodePtr node = src.Head;
    while (node != nullptr)
    {
        AddTail(node->Item);
        node = node->Next;
    }
}
```

And having a working copy constructor makes the assignment operator, thanks to the [Copy and Swap Idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom), also laughably simple:

```
LinkedList & LinkedList::operator=(LinkedList src) 
// pass by reference performs the copy
{
    std::swap(Head, src.Head); // now just swap the head of the copy 
                               // for the head of the source
    return *this;
} // destructor fires for src and cleans up all the nodes that were on this list
```

To finish off [The Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) trifecta we need a destructor. This, like 
the copy constructor is an application of DRY: Call your node removal function over and over until the list is empty. A removal function is an almost certain requirement of any linked list, so here I'm going to assume that there is one called `Remove`.

```
LinkedList::~LinkedList()
{
    while (Head != nullptr)
    {
        NodePtr temp = Head;
        Remove(Head);
        delete temp;
    }
}
```

So now based on two functions that a Linked List cannot function without anyway we have implemented all of the other functions required for basic maintenance. All you need are tested and bug-free `Add` and `Remove` functions and the rest comes practically free of charge.

And because the `AddTail` function hits one of my pet peaves... Here is a trick to greatly reduce the complexity of the function:

```
void LinkedList::AddTail(int Item)
{
    NodePtr *Crnt = &Head; // instead of pointing where Head points, point at 
                           // Head now we don't care if it is head or any 
                           // other node's Next. They are all abstracted to 
                           // the same thing: A pointer to where the next 
                           // node can be found        
    while (*Crnt != NULL) // keep looking until end of list
    {
        Crnt = &(*Crnt)->Next; // by pointing at the next Next pointer
    }
    //Add item to the tail of the linked list
    NodePtr node = new Node;
    node->Item = Item;
    node->Next = NULL;
    *Crnt = node; // Now just plop the new node over top of the terminating NULL
}
```

The `Remove` function, which I'm leaving unimplemented, uses the same pointer -to-pointer trick.

Answer (score 2):

try this (https://ideone.com/9lywXc using your original posted code)

```
LinkedList::LinkedList(const LinkedList& other):Head(nullptr)
{
    cout << "copy constructor called:\n";
    if(other.Head == nullptr) return;
    NodePtr dummyHead = new Node;
    NodePtr curr = dummyHead;
    NodePtr othcurr = other.Head;
    for(; othcurr!=nullptr; othcurr = othcurr->Next)
    {
        curr->Next = new Node;
        curr = curr->Next;
        cout << (curr->Item = othcurr->Item) << ",";
        curr->Next = nullptr;
    }
    Head = dummyHead->Next;
    delete dummyHead;
}


int main()
{
    LinkedList la;
    la.AddTail(30);
    la.AddTail(60);
    la.AddTail(90);
    LinkedList lb(la);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

copy constructor called:

30,60,90,

Comment: Works, but way too much work for something that can be done in a few lines of code.

Comment: I don't have enough cred yet to comment on your post. I need 4 more. 

I liked your reply except a copy constructor using AddTail has O(n^2) complexity. does a full list traversal for each new node added.

Yes, could use a tail pointer, etc, but I wanted to give a usable and decipherable answer without upgrading the asker. still, I think your overall message is better.

Comment: More of an N Log N, but yeah. Didn't claim it was efficient, just easy to write. Frankly that's the least of your worries with linked list efficiency. You should see poorly how it performs with caches. Stroustrup has a great piece on it: https://isocpp.org/blog/2014/06/stroustrup-lists Video well worth watching.

Comment: A smarter add function that allows you to specify where to insert also makes the copy faster `NodePtr Add(NodePtr after, int value)` would short circuit almost all of the traversal and match your performance.

Comment: yeah. chasing pointers, I know. chandler carruth goes nuts on linked lists in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fHNmRkzxHWs
also, this should be using smart pointers, etc.
and if you are copying lists then why are you doing that. either way asker now has multiple ways and perspectives on doing this

Answer (score 2):

this is an improvement on user4581301 prior answer so that copy constructor is O(n) on input list size. keep track of the tail with a single extra pointer in your encapsulating list class:

```
class LinkedList
{
public:
    LinkedList():Head(nullptr),Tail(nullptr){}
    LinkedList(const LinkedList& other);
    ~LinkedList() = default;                  // destructor
    void AddTail(int);              // adds item to tail
private:
    NodePtr Head;

    //KEEP TRACK OF TAIL POINTER WITH EXTRA MEMBER
    NodePtr Tail;
};

//via user4581301 response
LinkedList::LinkedList(const LinkedList & src):Head(nullptr),Tail(nullptr)
{
    NodePtr node = src.Head;
    while (node != nullptr)
    {
        AddTail(node->Item);
        node = node->Next;
    }
}

//Adding on tail
void LinkedList::AddTail(int Item)
{
    NodePtr np = new Node{Item,nullptr};
    if(Tail == nullptr && Head == nullptr)
        Head = Tail = np;
    else
    {
        Tail->Next = np;
        Tail = Tail->Next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the answer works fine, but i have got a confusion what does `:` means in
`LinkedList::LinkedList(const LinkedList & src):Head(nullptr),Tail(nullptr)`. Heard about `::` but not `:`.

Comment: its called a constructor initializer list. its the way to initialize member variables directly instead of in constructor body via
{
    foo = 5;
//...etc
}
technically the constructor body runs AFTER the initializer list performs its initialization. 
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list
http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html

Comment: @Pattrick The initializer list is one of the most important and least taught concepts in C++. It allows you to initialize member variables and base classes before entering the body of a constructor. All members must be fully constructed before entering the body of the constructor, sometimes resulting in you initializing the same objects twice. The time savings can be enormous in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

regarding testing:
you can add functionality to spit out the contents of the list. or you can subclass it into a test extension. or you can break encapsulation like this, using operator<<() :

```
class LinkedList
{
public:
    LinkedList():Head(nullptr),Tail(nullptr){}
    LinkedList(const LinkedList& other);
    ~LinkedList() = default;                  // destructor
    void AddTail(int);              // adds item to tail

    //breaks encapsulation but make some nice sugar to look inside
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& s, LinkedList& l)
    {
        s << "list contents: ";
        NodePtr c = l.Head;
        for(; c!=nullptr;c=c->Next)
            s << c->Item << " ";
        s << endl;
        return s;
    }
private:
    NodePtr Head;
    NodePtr Tail;
};
```

so that

```
int main()
{
    LinkedList la;
    la.AddTail(30);
    la.AddTail(60);
    la.AddTail(90);
    LinkedList lb(la);
    cout << lb;
    return 0;
}
```

spits out:
list contents: 30 60 90